# ¿Como cambiar datos de variables en glDatepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-datepicker

Buenos días comunidad de programadores, tengo un problema y es el siguiente, tengo el siguiente código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mydate').glDatePicker(
    {
       showAlways: false,
       hideOnClick: true,
       allowMonthSelect: false,
       allowYearSelect: false,
       // prevArrow: '',
       // nextArrow: '',
       selectedDate: new Date(2018, 05, 17),

       selectableDates: [
           { date: new Date(2018, 05, 20) },
           { date: new Date(2018, 05, 25) }
       ]

    });
});
```

y quiero reemplazar los valores de la fecha de

```
selectableDates: [
    { date: new Date(2018, 05, 20) },
    { date: new Date(2018, 05, 25) }
]
```

Aquí me gustaría colocar fechas que yo traiga de un formulario por ejemplo que del formulario venga algo así

```
var fecha = '{ date: new Date(2018, 05, 19) }, { date: new Date(2018, 05, 20) }'
```

y que esta variable al insertarla en selectableDates me tome esas fechas. 
Lo he hecho pero no me funciona. Les agradecería mucho a todos muchachos, yo se que debe ser algo sencillo pero soy un poco novato en esto.

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado

Comment: he intentado reemplazar esto:  por ejemplo:  var fecha = '{ date: new Date(2018, 05, 19) }, { date: new Date(2018, 05, 20) }'   y colocarlo de esta manera:      selectableDates: [
    fecha 
]     pero nada no me sale

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo asi:

```
var fecha = [
    { date: new Date(2018, 05, 19) },
    { date: new Date(2018, 05, 20) }
];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mydate').glDatePicker(
  {
     showAlways: false,
     hideOnClick: true,
     allowMonthSelect: false,
     allowYearSelect: false,
     // prevArrow: '',
     // nextArrow: '',
     selectedDate: new Date(2018, 05, 17),

     selectableDates: fecha

  });
});
```

Comment: gracias @alanfcm,  intenté lo que me indicaste pero nada, no me reconoce la variable cuando la coloco a  **selectableDates: fecha** y me muestra el calendario sin ningún día seleccionado, osea que no recibio el valor de la variable.